# Kingdom hearts how do I get the evening start on my journey?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

In the beginning of KH 1 you are asked three questions. What are the combinations to get each time of day because I'm trying to get the evening so that I don't struggle as much with powering up and leveling up later on in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Kingdom Hearts strategy wiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts/Awakening): With Tidus asking the 1st question, Wakka asking the 2nd question, and Selphie asking the 3rd question; the possible combinations are this:
[image: Combinations]